# How can I convert an $n$-dimensional vector to a 2d point?

Tags: vectors

I have a $n$-dimensional vector / sequence of values, how can I convert it to a 2D representation of such vector?

Follow-up: if I had a time-sequence in which every frame is $n$-dimensional, how can I convert it to a 2D point?

Comment: You cannot reduce dimension without losing some information. Just as a picture of a 3d object cannot give  its size. So you need to be more specific (what type of data compression are you looking for), and, still, there won't be clear cut answers.

Comment: There is talk about a $1$-pixel-camera.

Answer (score 0):

What Maesumi said in the comments is false. The answer is going to need more information of what exactly is the context. In principle, theoretically, we can store all $n$-vectors in just real numbers: Form a real number $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ between zero and one in the following way.

Divide all components of the $n$-vector by some $10^M$ such that all are numbers in $[0,1]$

In the digits $a_j$ of position $j$ congruent to $i$, for $i=1,2,..,n$, mod $n+1$ store the digits of the $i$-th component of the vector (after the division by $10^M$). In the digits of position multiple of $n+1$ store the digits of $M$.

All the information of the vector can be stored in a single number. So, in 2D you even have an extra dimension to play around.

Comment: This is true in principle but not in practice. Maesumi was addressing the physical limitations of such an exercise and is entirely right in that context.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Again, the "physical limitation" doesn't make any sense unless the concrete problem is specified. What is physical? Rational coordinates? If such, Maesumi is even more wrong because this and many other codings can be applied to again do the conversion. You both are confusing the need for a coding with continuous injections, or homeomorphisms, or something of the sort.